# Finding a region where a function is periodic

Tags: autocorrelation

I am looking for a method to find the region where a function is periodic. So, for example, I have a function that is periodic in some places and not in others, I would want to know the range of x values where it is periodic.
 I'm trying to do this in matlab and I tried to use autocorrelation but I can't use it to find the original range where the signal is periodic

Comment: I think, windowed Fourier would be more helpful.

Comment: Could you explain how/point me to resources that explain in layperson's terms how to?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform